# how to convert an object data type into UIElement in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I declared an object data type

```
object itemize;
```

then i created a method with conditions, depending on the condition, the itemize will be assigned into a corresponding UserControl

```
public void StackFilter(string mode)
{
    this.stkFilter.Children.Clear();

    switch(mode)
    {
        case "FilterWithType":
            itemize = new FilterWithTypesUC();
            break;
        case "FilterBasic":
            itemize = new FilterBasicUC();
            break;
    }
    this.stkFilter.Children.Add(itemize);
}
```

it says I can't add the itemize as the stack panel's child because it is not an UIElement type. Ho how do I make it as UIElement?

Comment: have u  tried   this.stkFilter.Children.Add(itemize as UIElement); ?

Comment: this.stkFilter.Children.Add((UIElement)itemize);

Comment: I tried the best answer that I chose, it worked fine, but it is good to have alternative styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you to declare it as `UIElement` itself. Then you don't need a cast.

```
UIElement itemize;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the element to `UIElement` i.e

`this.stkFilter.Children.Add(itemize as UIElement);`